# Power BI Matrix - List with description to right and values to left

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Hello i'm in need of some expert help with a Matrix, i'm trying to created a matrix where the column heading to the left, then the value to the right for multiple rows.  I'm not sure if this is possible with a matrix but looking for any suggestions are greatly appreciated! [image: Matrix Example]

Comment: This is what you will get if you use `Table` instead of `Matrix`.

Comment: Does [values on rows](https://powerbidocs.com/2020/10/09/show-values-on-rows-for-matrix-visual/) work for you?